# Failure not capturing in Unix command when redirecting the java/Spark logs

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to pass the Java/Spark processing logs to log_msg function and in the next line I am having result=&? where failure is not capturing of Java or Spark processing in Unix.

```
    log_msg () {
  if [ -n "${1}" ]; then
    echo ${1}
  else
    while read IN
    do 
      echo $IN
    done
  fi
}
 failure () {
    echo ${1}
}

log_msg "Program Begins"
sh deltaspark.sh |& log_msg
result=$?
if [ "$result" -ne 0 ]; then
   failure "There was an error"
fi
```

But when I try to write Spark/Java processing log using redirection >> spark.log 2>&1 then result=$? captures 0 for success and failure for 1.
From the logic above, after passing processing logs to function log_msg , the result=&? is not giving 1 for failure case.

How we do need to handle this case in Unix

Comment: `true|&true;echo $?; false|&true;echo $?; true|&false;echo $?`

Comment: Since you're using bash, consider `pipefail` and `PIPESTATUS`

Comment: Note that `while read IN; do echo $IN; done` is quite buggy. _At minimum_ make it `while IFS= read -r in; do printf '%s\n' "$in"; done`. As it is, you lose backslashes, runs of whitespace get collapsed down to a single space, any word that looks like a glob expression gets replaced with a list of matching filenames in the current directory, etc. And it's also nonobvious what you accomplish by doing this in the first place; it's _much_ slower to have the shell read and rewrite output than it is to just let your underlying program write it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit status of a pipe is the status of the last command which is the function `log_msg`.

As an alternative to using `bash`'s features `pipefail` and `PIPESTATUS` as proposed in a comment, you could replace the pipe with redirection

```
sh deltaspark.sh > >( log_msg ) 2>&1
```

or

```
sh deltaspark.sh >& >( log_msg )
```